# Print a double with its precision

Tags: c++, double, precision

I've got a third party library that read values from laboratory scales. This library interface many scale models, each one with its own precision.
What I need to do in my C++ application (that uses that library) is to read the weight value from the scale (double format) and print it, taking into account the scale precision (so giving the user, reading that value, the information about scale precision).

So, connecting a scale with 2 decimals precision, the output should be for example: 23.45 g
Instead, connecting a scale with 4 decimals precision, the output should be for example: 23.4567 g

The fact is I don't know from the library the scale precision.
The function looks like the following:

```
double value = scale.Weight();
```

If I just print the double value, the output could be in the form of:

```
1.345999999999999
```

instead of:

```
1.346
```

Is there a way to understand the double precision so that the output shows the weight with the scale precision?

EDIT: scale precision goes from 0 to 6 decimals.

Comment: ahhh... you need to get the precision out of the value?! sorry, i missunderstood your question...

Comment: @user1810087: correct, sorry for my explanation/English lang.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what it is that you really need to do - it's not obvious as it stands.

Comment: @PaulR: I'm worried about adding more confusion if editing.. :-) can you edit it for me?

Comment: It is not possible to get the precision from a double(even if by human), how can you make sure `1.345999999999999` is not 15 precision? The library you use should give you that kind of information.

Comment: @appleapple: ok, I understand. I've edit the question to cover this case: the maximum precision of a scale is 6 decimals. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @ABCplus If you know the precision, you can format the output as you want. But it is impossible to get the precision from a double. You need something else, maybe the library gives you the information, or you can ask the user to input it.

Comment: @ABCplus If the maximum precision is 6, why don't you print just exactly this precision? If it is not necessary that the value is precise (and i assume it isn't) you could round at this precision (or at this +1), too.

Answer (score 1):

No. This information should be inside `scale` class as `double` type has "fixed" precision and you cannot change it. Also type precision and printed precision are two different things. You can use type that has infinite precision but show always 2 digits after dot etc. If `scale` do not have precision information you could do a helper class and hard code precision inside it then correlate it with some `scale` property or type.